# enumerated list in proof - margin, qed symbol

Tags: amsthm

[image]

I have two questions.
1. Can I delete the red-colored space?
2. If I use enumerate in proof, QED symbol appears the next line of the end, as above. If I do not want to type manually \qedhere, should I use ntheorem?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep, label=(\arabic*)}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lem}
\begin{enumerate}
\item xxxx
\item yyyy
\end{enumerate}
\end{lem}
\begin{proof}
\begin{enumerate}
\item xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. 
\item yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. \end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A low-tech solution to both problems is to not use the enumerate environment, but just type `(1)` and `(2)` manually and use paragraphs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`amsthm` already has the mechanism, called `\qedhere`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep, label=(\arabic*)}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lem}
\begin{enumerate}
\item xxxx
\item yyyy
\end{enumerate}
\end{lem}
\begin{proof}
\begin{enumerate}

\item xxxx xxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx. xxxxx xxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx. xxxxx xxx xxxxxx xxxxx 
xxxxxx. xxxxx xxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx. xxxxx xxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx. xxxxx xxx xxxxxx xxxxx 
xxxxxx.

\item yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyy 
yyy yyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy. 
yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy.\qedhere
\end{enumerate}

\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

You can use it also at the end of displayed equations.

[image]

If you want to remove the indent, just don't use `enumerate`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep, label=(\arabic*)}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lem}
\begin{enumerate}
\item xxxx
\item yyyy
\end{enumerate}
\end{lem}
\begin{proof}
(1) xxxx xxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx. xxxxx xxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx. xxxxx xxx xxxxxx xxxxx 
xxxxxx. xxxxx xxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx. xxxxx xxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx. xxxxx xxx xxxxxx xxxxx 
xxxxxx.

(2) yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyy 
yyy yyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy. 
yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here are the right enumitem parameters for the enumerate environments:

```
        \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
        \usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

        \usepackage[english]{babel}
        \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \usepackage{amsthm}
        \usepackage{amssymb}
        \usepackage{textcomp}
        \usepackage{enumitem}
        \setlist[enumerate]{nosep, label=(\arabic*)}

        \theoremstyle{definition}
        \newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

        \begin{document}

        \begin{lem}
        \begin{enumerate}[wide,labelindent = 0pt, labelwidth = ! ]
        \item xxxx
        \item yyyy
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{lem}
        \begin{proof}
        \begin{enumerate}[wide,labelindent = 0pt, labelwidth = ! ]
        \item xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
        \item yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. \end{enumerate}
        \end{proof}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the labels to be indented, don't write anything about `labelindent`: with the `wide` parameter, it is set by default to `labelindent=`parindent`, and the parameter given here simply overwrites this value.

As for the theorem symbol, `ntheorem` handles it `automatically`(I used the `standard` set of theorems, but it can be entirely customised):

```
        \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
        \usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar,  noheadfoot]{geometry}

        \usepackage[english]{babel}
        \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        %\usepackage{amsthm}
        \usepackage[standard, thmmarks, amsmath]{ntheorem}
        \usepackage{enumitem}
        \setlist[enumerate]{nosep, label=(\arabic*)}

        \theoremstyle{definition}
        \newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

        \begin{document}

        \begin{Lemma}
        \begin{enumerate}[wide,labelindent = 0pt, labelwidth = ! ]
        \item xxxx
        \item yyyy
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{Lemma}

        \begin{Proof}
        \begin{enumerate}[wide,labelindent = 0pt, labelwidth = ! ]
        \item xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx. xxxxx xxxxxx xxxx xx xxxxx xxx. xxxxx xxxxxxx xxx xxx xxx xxxx. xxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxx xxxxxxx. xxxx xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx.
        \item yyyyy yyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyy yyyyyyy. yyyyyyyy yyyy. yyyyyy yyyyyy. yyyyy yyyyyyy. yyyyy yyy yyyy. yyyyyy yyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyyyyyyyyy. yyyyy yyyyyyy. \end{enumerate}

        \end{Proof}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In such cases I use `\qedhere` at the end of the environment. And to avoid the awkward `Proof: (1) Bla bla bla` line, I'd write a short introduction as to why the proof is split into cases. Your gentle reader will thank you.